# Marcar checkboxes conforme indicado em um JSON

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Tenho uma tabela com duas linhas e tres colunas todas com um conjunto de checkbox. 
A ideia é marcar como checked atraves de uma json string `var rs = [{"cklist":"1;1;1"},{"cklist":"0;0;0"}];` sendo que o `cklist[0]` representa os ceckboxes no row 1, e `cklist[1]` para o row 2. Ex: 1 significa checked e 0 não checked. Alguma ideia de como fazer isso funcionar?

tentei o codigo abaixo sendo que todas colunas da fileira 1 deveriam estar checked e somente a 2nd coluna e ficou marcada.

```js
var rs = [{"cklist":"1;1;1"},{"cklist":"0;0;0"}];
/*primeiro row dos checkboxs deveriam ficar checked 
   conforme z = rs[p].cklist.split(';');
   */
var rows = 2;

for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
  for(p=0;p<30;p++){ 

    var z = rs[p].cklist.split(';');
    for(j=0; j<z.length;j++){

      //set checkbox true ou false
      if( z[j] == 0 ){ var zz = 'false'; }else{ var zz = 'true';} 

      $('#tts'+p+' td:eq('+p+') input:checkbox').attr("checked", zz);
      //alert(zz )
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id='tts1'>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='tts2'>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Quando escreves `for(p=0;p<30;p++){` isso implica que `rs` tem de ter pelo menos 29 objetos dentro. Eu só vejo 2... esse é o problema numero 1 a meu ver.

Answer (score 0):

Assim como o @Sergio apontou, os seus laços não fazem o menor sentido.

Em todo caso, você só precisar percorrer cada elemento do Array `rs`, então percorrer os valores de cada `object.cklist.split(";")`.

Como o Array possui o mesmo numero de elementos que linhas no tabela, e cada objeto no array pode ser dividido em numero semelhante ao das colunas, então fica facil interar ambos.

```js
var tb = document.querySelector("table");
var rs = [{"cklist":"1;1;1"},{"cklist":"0;0;0"}];

for (var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
  var cklist = rs[i].cklist.split(";");
  var cboxes = tb.rows[i].querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");      
  for (var j = 0; j < cklist.length; j++) {
    cboxes[j].checked = cklist[j] == 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id='tts1'>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='tts2'>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria. Só que o raciocínio lógico não encaixava. Obrigado pela atenção. Valeu!